# How to setup a multi node Elasticsearch cluster using Amazon AMI

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami

How to setup a multi-node Elasticsearch cluster (single master node, data node) using Amazon AMI

Is it possible to set this up by using an AMI, so that I can launch whenever I need?

Any inputs here really appreciated.

Thanks!